# Error from WebClient: "The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable"

Tags: c#, web-services, webclient

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    Uri urls = new Uri(url);
    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.76 Safari/537.36";
    dokuman.Load(wc.OpenRead(urls), Encoding.UTF8);
}

dokuman.Load(wc.OpenRead(urls), Encoding.UTF8);
```

> The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.

Sometimes I get this error. How can we solve this?

Comment: You should fix the server side application. 503 status code means that the server is not available to process the client request. There's nothing you could do on the client.

Comment: ...or network issue preventing you reaching it

Comment: Use fiddler to get the browser request that works, and compare it to the request generated by your application. You'll see differences, work to fix those.

Comment: Url=https://www.google.com.tr/search?sclient=psy-ab&site=&source=hp&q=cars+&btnG=Ara    Page connect, but gives an error c#..

Comment: Can you show examples?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - What if services are working using Postman? what could be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this utility function it supports proxies too

```
 public static string GetPageHtml(string link, System.Net.WebProxy proxy = null)
        {
            System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient() { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 };
            client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
            if (proxy != null)
            {
                client.Proxy = proxy;
            }

            using (client)
            {
                try
                {
                    return client.DownloadString(link);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }

        }
```

Try it, if it doesn't work then you probably got blocked by google because you were making requests fast, to avoid getting blocked you should use web proxies or make reasonable pauses between your requests.

Example

```
var Html = GetPageHtml("https://www.google.com.tr/search?sclient=psy-ab&site=&source=hp&q=cars+&btnG=Ara");
```

Comment: I don't see any significant difference to what OP is doing in this answer.

Comment: Probably best not to mention that here then given that you're almost certainly contravening their Ts&Cs. :)

Comment: why does it look like you are trying to use .NET 1.0?